# Special Characters in Java Enums

Tags: java, enums, special-characters

Currently attempting to have special characters, primarily '.' a number, however, it seems enums require letters only. Is there a way to use special characters? Currently trying to make a file saver and many file types have numbers in them, an example being:

```
public enum FileType {

    7z(".7z"),
    ace(".ace"),
    apk(".apk"),
    bz2(".bz2"),
    crx(".crx"),
    dd(".dd"),
    deb(".deb"),
    gz(".gz"),
    gzip(".gzip"),
    jar(".jar"),
    rar(".rar"),
    rpm(".rpm"),
    sit(".sit"),
    sitx(".sitx"),
    snb(".snb"),
    tar(".tar"),
    tar.gz(".tar.gz"),
    tqz(".tqz"),
    zip(".zip"),
    zipx(".zipx");

    public final String FILESUFFIX;

    FileType(String FileSuffix) {
        this.FILESUFFIX = FileSuffix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return FILESUFFIX;
    }
}
```

I have looked throughout StackOverflow, however, I haven't found a way that suited me. I do not understand how to do 'maps' or the other fancy stuff, so is there an alternate way to simple get something like `mp4` to be an Enum?

Comment: I think you should use uppercase names for all enum constants, and use `SEVEN_ZIP` to avoid starting with a digit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this value declared in the enum **7z** is  invalid same as you can not declare a variable with the name 7z since that will be an ***invalid java identifier***
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbuk/index.html

alternative to that you can play with underscores,and something better is use UPPER_CASE

```
public enum FileType {

    _7Z(".7z"),
    _ACE(".ace"),
    _APK(".apk"),
    _BZ2(".bz2"),
    _CRX(".crx"),
    etc etc
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That was actually a pretty clever solution!

Answer (score 4):

Enum identifiers follow the same [rules as other Java identifiers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-identifiers/):

> The only allowed characters for identifiers are all alphanumeric characters([A-Z],[a-z],[0-9]), ‘$‘(dollar sign) and ‘_‘ (underscore).
>
> Identifiers should not start with digits([0-9]). For example “123geeks” is a not a valid java identifier.
>
> Java identifiers are case-sensitive

From your example, `mp4` is a valid identifier, but `7z` is not (because it starts with a number)

Note: by convention, enum identifiers are typically all uppercase.

Comment: [JLS link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), and links to [Character.isJavaIdentifierStart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart-int-) and [Character.isJavaIdentifierPart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart-int-).

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.ecom.test;

enum SpecialChars {
    PIPELINE_SYMBOL("|"), FORWARD_SLASH("/");

    private String value;

    private SpecialChars(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value; // will return , or ' instead of COMMA or APOSTROPHE
    }

}
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        System.out.println(SpecialChars.PIPELINE_SYMBOL);
        System.out.println(SpecialChars.FORWARD_SLASH);

        }
}
```